# Why getScore() api of EntityAnnotation class returns zero all time?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

I am using google vision api for Text Detection of images which gives response in JSON format. So this response belongs to com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation.From EntityAnnotation object I am trying to get the value using getScore() of EntityAnnotation. But every time it returns 0 and I am expecting some float value rather than just 0. Has anybody faced similar issue ? To understand the google vision text detection api, you can go through this https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr Help appreciated.Thanks.

I tried the same input with LABEL_DETECTION tag provided by google vision api. For that it returns some values between 0 to 1 rather than just zero. But it's not working for same input with TEXT_DETECTION tag. I tested on windows-10

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath); ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
    final ByteString imageBytes = ByteString.readFrom(inputStream);
    final Image image = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imageBytes).build();
    final Feature feature = Feature.newBuilder().setType(TEXT_DETECTION).build();
    final AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feature).setImage(image)
        .build();
    requests.add(request);

    final BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
    final List < AnnotateImageResponse > responseList = response.getResponsesList();

    result = responseList.get(0).getTextAnnotationsList();
}

final EntityAnnotation annotation = result.get(0);
final Float score = annotation.getScore();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no score for TEXT_DETECTION. Try expanding the "response" to see an example of attributes being returned for TEXT_DETECTION: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

You may be interested in [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type) and [full_text_annotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.TextAnnotation), which has [confidence](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.Page).